# dont understand where this action takes in form action wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am new to wordpress and trying to modify theme. but i am not able to track form action.

```
<form action="<?php echo appthemes_get_registration_url( 'login_post' ); ?>" method="post" class="login-form register-form custom" name="registerform" id="login-form">
```

where these action takes ? how data is stored ?
this is the function.php where i get following function code .

```
function appthemes_get_registration_url( $context = 'display' ) {
    if ( current_theme_supports( 'app-login' ) && ( $page_id = APP_Registration::get_id() ) ) {
        $url = get_permalink( $page_id );
    } else {
        $url = site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=register' );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
        $url = add_query_arg( 'redirect_to', urlencode( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ), $url );
    }

    return esc_url( $url, null, $context );
}
```

can anyone help me with this issue?
i am stuck here.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: modifying registration form with more fields.. but unable to store extra fields in table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the function being used

```
$url = get_permalink( $page_id );
```

The above code will get the link of the current custom login page which the theme uses.

Or else it will go to the default WordPress register page

```
$url = site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=register' );
```

There is a redirect field in the theme after the registration is over, which makes the user to go to the required page. If it is empty, then it can be skipped or else it is returned to the redirect URL specified.

```
if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
    $url = add_query_arg( 'redirect_to', urlencode( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ), $url );
}
```

The data of your registration is stored in a table called `users` which you can access through `PHPmyAdmin`

Comment: thanks... i have another question here.. <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $form_action ); ?>" > where this function takes me ? i cant find any solution

Comment: `return esc_url( $url, null, $context );` It depends on the function. It can take you to Admin dashboard or front page or an error page depending on the user role and user credentials.

Comment: Then it will take you to the completed project page.

Comment: It will be stored in wp_posts or if you are using any custom plugin for this, they have a separate table. You have to search in PHPmyadmin. The data storage functionality is included in wp-includes.

Comment: This one -> http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/21/interacting-with-the-wordpress-database/ and Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb